# cakephp use a calculated field in mysql field list

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am trying to return a mysql field that has had the mysql `REPLACE` function applied to it before it is returned to Cake. I am actually trying to remove text from a field if it matches my variable.

Theoretically inside the find, I want:

```
'fields' => array('REPLACE(E.title, "'.$data['Make']['name'].'", "") AS E.title', ...)
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: ..and what happens when you tried this? Do you have an error?

Comment: I'm smelling SQL injection vulnerabilities. Please use [**`DboSource::value()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-DboSource.html#_value) to quote the input properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) in your model

```
class ModelName extends AppModel {
    public $virtualFields = array(
        "my_virtual_field_title" => "REPLACE(yourfield,'OLD STR','NEW STR')"
    );
}
```

using :

```
$your_query= $this->ModelName->find('first');
echo $your_query['ModelName']['my_virtual_field_title'];
```

or you can set directly the virtualfields :

```
$this->ModelName->virtualFields['my_virtual_field_title'] = "
    CASE 
        WHEN title = 'custom text' THEN 'custom result'
        .
        . 
        .
        ELSE ''
    END
";
```

more information : 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: the problem is I don't know what the variable is until i run the find. How do I inject it into the find using a virtual field?

Comment: do you have `$data['Make']['name']` before call find ?

Comment: ok , so use directly call for virtual fields as my update. read the documentations http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Comment: Sorted. Basically what you said but without the CASE ELSE (just the REPLACE) and setting a default in the model (not a formula).

Comment: As per conventions your field name should better be lowercase: `my_virtual_field_title` etc